# Remove Key From Json Dict/ Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I Just started writing this script for practice,
it will take input and then write it inside Json file.
Code looks like this:

```
import json


command = int(input("Do You Want To Add, Or Remove From List? 1/2 "))
if command == 1:
    add_key = input("Type In key Name: ")
    add_val1 = input("Type In Value N1: ")
    add_val2 = input("Type In Value N2: ")

    with open('jjj.json', 'r+') as jjson:
        tvsh = json.load(jjson)
        new_tvsh = {add_key: [add_val1, add_val2]}
        tvsh.update(new_tvsh)
        jjson.seek(0)
        json.dump(tvsh, jjson)
elif command == 2:
    with open('jjj.json', 'r+') as jjson:
        tvsh = json.load(jjson)
        chooseremove = input("Choose Key To Remove: ")
        try:
            del tvsh[chooseremove]
        except KeyError as ex:
            print(f"No such key: {chooseremove} ")
        jjson.seek(0)
        json.dump(tvsh, jjson)
```

Json File Looks Like This:

```
{"Key1":["Val1","Val2"],"Key2":["Val1","Val2"],"Key3":["Val1","Val2"]}
```

But when i try to remove key(For example key3) my json file will be like this:

```
{"Key1":["Val1","Val2"],"Key2":["Val1","Val2"]} "Key3":["Val1","Val2"]}
```

it's taking key outside dict but adding "}" at the end
Any Ideas what can i do?

EDIT: Also Tried .pop but same result

Comment: Try creating a [mcve], which does not take user input but only does what is needed to reproduce the problem when it is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error here is that running `jjson.seek(0)` followed by `json.dump(tvsh, jjson)` does not destroy the contents of the existing file, it only overwrites it. Since the data structure you are writing to the JSON file after remove `Key3` is smaller, the entire file is not overwritten (i.e., the  `"Key3":["Val1","Val2"]}` is left over from your first write).

The solution here is to run `jjson.truncate()` after running `json.dump(tvsh, jjson)`.

The following program shows the difference, without depending on user input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json

# Test data
initial_data = {
    "Key1":["Val1", "Val2"],
    "Key2":["Val1", "Val2"],
    "Key3":["Val1", "Val2"],
}
final_data = {
    "Key1":["Val1", "Val2"],
    "Key2":["Val1", "Val2"],
}

with open('testA.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(initial_data, f)
    f.seek(0)
    json.dump(final_data, f)

with open('testB.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(initial_data, f)
    f.seek(0)
    json.dump(final_data, f)
    f.truncate()
```